# 401 Unauthorised error from one device but success from another device

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am creating an application in Xamarin Forms for iOS and android. In VS, the test code works perfectly every time, with a response code of "OK" (200). However, in another little project which will work alongside the mobile apps (written in windows forms (.NET)), the EXACT same code, username, password, url, returns error "Unauthorised" (401).

The url in question that doesn't work is http://192.168.8.193/get.cgi?id=26&sid=255.
BUT
another url of similar function DOES work: http://-Hidden-/get.cgi?id=26&sid=255.

```
public static async Task<string> TestConnection(string url, string username, string password)
        {
            url = url + PanelCommands.GET_URL + PanelCommands.CONNECT_URL;

            if (GetInternetConnectivity())
            { 

                NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential { UserName = username, Password = password };

                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credential };
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);                

                try
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e);
                    return "Failed";
                }
            }
```

I have tried pre-authenticating, adding authentication headers, etc. But nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine. You have `catch (Exception e)` in that code, wich is a cardinal sin of Exception handling. And if you got it here, you might get it in other places too. Like the other programm or even the Service you ar accessing. There are two articles on the mater I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: It could be a Networking propblem. The general rules is that the Network related classes do not care if the other end is on the same Computer, the same switch or the Voyager 2 Probe. If it works against localhost but not anywhere else, it is a Networking problem.

Comment: Well that's what I am thinking. We can access the device on the other end of that link fine, if running vs on Mac, the app on iOS or android. but CAN'T run it on vs for windows. Could this be an issue anywhere? For the record, I have tried it on 2 windows machines on the local network, and a windows machine at home, all of which had the same error.

Comment: If it does not work on Windows but it does work on mac, it is propably the service rejecting it if there is any sign of Windows. Apple Systems are the ones prone to not talk with non-Apple. | There is a off-chance that it is the Windows Firefall. But then the error should be a "can not reach" rather then Unauthorized. You need to look in the service you are trying to access.

Comment: Do you have proxy server setup in your network? It's possible the un-authorized exception is coming from proxy server and not from the actual service.

Comment: There isn't a proxy server, the device I am trying to connect to is like a mini server connected to a device running in the office, it is connected to our network via ethernet cable. 
There isn't an exception either, it runs through the code fine, and returns the string "Unauthorised". In a piece of code which I have removed from this snippet, I am debugging a serialised version of the result object so I can view the auth etc, but it all seems fine there?

Answer (score 0):

> The URL in question that doesn't work is http://192.168.8.193/get.cgi?id=26&sid=255.

First of all, I think you are missing the port in your URL. It should be something like http://192.168.8.193:5000/get.cgi?id=26&sid=255.

Edit: This is something I got wrong. You can perfectly have a URL without a specific port.

Secondly, your firewall may be blocking the connection between your projects, if they are running in different devices. You can try adding an inbound rule following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule) for Windows 10 (it is somewhat similar in other versions of windows as well).

Comment: we have two urls, one is an internal url, the other is an external url, which is how I can access it when away from the office & network. on every other platform apart from vs for windows, BOTH urls work fine.

Comment: In terms of the firewall, vs and vs debugger is allowed, but I will try adding the inbound wall now. Thanks.

Comment: The inbound rule should be on your server (in this case in your device with IP 192.168.8.193).

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible to be honest. Its a VERY old java device which is connected to the network, it doesn't have an accessible interface or anything like that. But even if it did require inbound rules, it works on every other device bar windows so that wouldn't be correct anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Sacked this off. Rewrote the project in Xamarin UWP. Worked perfectly first time.